# Can I change the type of class I'm using inside a method with a template?

Tags: c++

I'm working with the [ROOT](https://root.cern/#:%7E:text=As%20high%2Dperformance%20software%2C%20ROOT,modify%20it%2C%20contribute%20to%20it!) language for some data analysis for my PhD, but the question I'm asking feels more C++ specific.

Right now I have two different methods that all do the same thing, and I'm hoping to condense this number down to one method that does everything to shorten my code. Here's a basic rundown of the first method (pseudocode):

```
int Method1(double arg1, double arg2)
{

// Do some math to set the Custom_Class arguments
double classArg1 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg1);
double classArg2 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg2);

Custom_Class* class = new Custom_Class(classArg1, classArg2);

// Do some more math
class->another_weird_math_function();

// Get output from CustomClass
int answer = class->GetAnswer();
return answer;
}
```

The second method looks something like this:

```
int Method2(double arg1, double arg2)
{

// Do some math to set the CustomClass arguments
double classArg1 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg1);
double classArg2 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg2);

A_Different_Custom_Class* class = new A_Different_Custom_Class(classArg1, classArg2);

// Do some more math
class->another_weird_math_function();

// Get output from CustomClass
int answer = class->GetAnswer();
return answer;
}
```

Both Custom_Class and A_Different_Custom_Class have the same inputs to their respective constructors and the same output, but they differ in how they calculate the final output answer.
What I'd like to do is write one method that allows me to specify which custom class I'd like to call inside the method. I know this isn't the proper way to do this, but something along the lines of

```
template <typename T>
int MasterMethod(double arg1, double arg2)
{

// Do some math to set the CustomClass arguments
double classArg1 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg1);
double classArg2 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg2);

T* class = new T(classArg1, classArg2);

// Do some more math
class->another_weird_math_function();

// Get output from CustomClass
int answer = class->GetAnswer();
return answer;
}
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: *" I know this isn't the proper way to do this"* - ¿What makes you think so?

Comment: Looks legal to me, apart from unrelated issues (`class` as a variable name, memory leak...).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do you come from a C# or Java environment, where `new` is required to create objects? In C++ you don't need to do that.

Comment: As for your problem, have you *tried* it? What problems did your attempt have? If you want help about the problems your attempt give you, please ask about them directly instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't, I only started using C++ based languages a few months ago. The 'new' standard comes from the tutorials I've done/other code I've read from the ROOT language.

Answer (score 0):

With some minor tweaks this would be legal C++:

```
template <typename T>
int MasterMethod(double arg1, double arg2)
{
  // Do some math to set the CustomClass arguments
  double classArg1 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg1);
  double classArg2 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg2);

  T calculator(classArg1, classArg2);

  // Do some more math
  calculator.another_weird_math_function();

  // Get output from CustomClass
  int answer = calculator.GetAnswer();
  return answer;
}
```

Note I did not use `new` to allocate `calculator` because it doesn't seem to need to live beyond the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of going for templates is good in your case (at least if your colleagues are not allergic). But there are several issues here.

1. Don't name your instance of T `class`. `class` is a C++ keyword. You cannot use a keyword as a variable/object name (or for anything else apart from the thing it was supposed to do for that matter).
2. You create your object T with `new`. This is dynamic allocation and (usually) mean that the life of your object should go beyond the life of the function. This does not seems to be the case here so a regular stack allocation should be fine (and above this, you never call delete on your object pointer so you have an obvious memory leak).
3. Indent your code.

It can look like this:

```
template <typename T>
int MasterMethod(double arg1, double arg2)
{

    // Do some math to set the CustomClass arguments
    double classArg1 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg1);
    double classArg2 = some_weird_math_function((arg1-arg2), arg2);

    T my_object(classArg1, classArg2);

    // Do some more math
    my_object.another_weird_math_function();

    // Get output from CustomClass
    int answer = my_object.GetAnswer();
    return answer;
}
```